# Negative coordinates of JPanels (and lack of cooperation with Timer)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Please note that this is a more theoretical question about problems with this approach, as I'm trying to understand the underlying mechanics - genuine curiosity. For the actual implementation I'm likely to use something different.

Say we have the following frame with a split pane. The right hand side of the split pane has a button to slide out a panel on the left and show another one in its place (here I'm using overlay layout to make it look smoother). The code is as follows:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.OverlayLayout;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {

   JPanel panel;
   JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
   public void makeUI() {

      panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
      panel.setLocation(0,0);
      JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
      panel3.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
      panel3.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,400));

      JPanel panelContainer = new JPanel();
      panelContainer.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(panelContainer));
      panelContainer.add(panel);
      panelContainer.add(panel3);


      JButton button = new JButton("slide out");
      // Slide out the red panel to reveal blue
      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ((JButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
            new Timer(1, new ActionListener() {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  panel.setLocation(panel.getX() - 1, 0);
                  if (panel.getX() + panel.getWidth() == 0) {
                     ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                     panel.setVisible(false);
               System.out.println("Timer stopped");
            }
               }
            }).start();
         }
      });

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sliding Panel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setSize(400, 400);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setLayout(null);

      splitPane.setDividerLocation(100);
      splitPane.setLeftComponent(panelContainer);
      JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
      panel2.add(button);
//      panel2.add(button2);
      panel2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,400));
      splitPane.setRightComponent(panel2);
      frame.setContentPane(splitPane);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            new Main().makeUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Now if I add a button that reverses the animation, by setting location to `(-panel.getWidth(), 0)` and then increase the x coordinate, this fails. In theory the code is the same, with the only differences being in the start position, end position, and increments. However it does no longer work.

```
  JButton button2 = new JButton("slide in");
  button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ((JButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        panel.setLocation(-panel.getWidth(),0);
        System.out.println(panel.getX()); // gives -99, which is about right
        new Timer(1, new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               System.out.println(panel.getX()); // starts from 0
              panel.setLocation(panel.getX() + 1, 0);
              System.out.println(panel.getX()); // keeps increasing until forcibly stopped
              if (panel.getX() == 0) {
                 ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
           System.out.println("Timer stopped");
        }
           }
        }).start();
     }
  });
```

More precisely the problem lies in the `new Timer(...)` line. As per console logging, setting location puts the X coordinate at -99, but two lines later it's at 0, and when increments occur, it goes on to infinity.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding how timers work, however after reading the documentation on it and JPanels, I still don't see why such an approach would not work. Not to mention that there is very little on negative coordinates of JPanels to begin with.

Thank you in advance for all the explanations!

**EDIT (27.07.2016)**

@camickr 's answer makes it work, however I still don't *undersand* it, although it helped me narrow the question a little:

Why is the layout re-done after setting the location to negative? What is causing it to be re-done?

Answer (score 1):

> In theory the code is the same, with the only differences being in the start position, end position, and increments

Actually it is not the same.

You play with the visibility of the panel and the logic is different depending on which button you click. I'm guessing the setVisible(true) statement is invoking the layout manager which is resetting the location of the component.

There is no need to change the visibility of the panel. Get rid of both `setVisible(...)` statements.

Also, you might want to keep the buttons enabled you can test sliding in/out repeatedly without restarting the program.

Edit:

> if that was the case, why does getX() gives -99

Because the layout hasn't been done when that statement is executed.

Code does not always execute sequentially. Sometimes Swing methods will use SwingUtiltites.invokeLater() to add code the end of the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

This is easy enough to verify. Just change your code as follows to see when the layout is invoked.

```
  JPanel panelContainer = new JPanel()
  {
    @Override
    public void doLayout()
    {
        System.out.println("layout");
        super.doLayout();
    }
  };
```

Comment: Perhaps it is invoking layout manager, but if that was the case, why does `getX()` gives -99 (panel's width should be 100, but that's close enough) **after** the panel has been set to visible? This is the bit I would like to understand. Thank you for the suggestion though, I will definitely make a note of that.

Comment: I'm afraid your action isn't satisfactory still. What's the order of execution of timer and layout? Why is the layout not done, when the location is set? OR why is it re-done after the location is set/when the timer starts?

Comment: @AgataB, the answer explains the problem. A Timer has nothing to do with the code in the ActionListener. The whole point of a Timer is to "schedule" an activity at some time in the future. So you set the location to -99, then the layout is done and the layout manager resets the value to 0. Did you even modify the code as I suggested to see the order of execution???